# Breaking change in 200 response status between 4.3 and 4.4?

Tags: angular

```
this.projectService.removeProject(projectId).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('deleted');
})
```

the service call looks like:

```
removeProject(id: number) {
   return this.httpClient.delete(`/api/projects/${id}`) 
}
```

where httpClient is :

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)
```

This has all been working fine until I upgraded from 4.3 to 4.4 and I am now getting:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:73)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:111)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1729)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:499)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1427)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1445)
```

I have just pinned this down to the following. My delete function returns a 200 response status:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            _projectRepository.Delete(id);
        }
```

If I get it to return something(anything just to prove) then it does indeed work fine:

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public Project Delete(int id)
        {
            _projectRepository.Delete(id);

            return new Project();
        }
```

This is a new issue purely from the upgrade. Presumably something has got stricter but I'm not sure how to handle?

Comment: The problem is specific to your particular case. I don't see how this can be directly connected to HttpClient in 4.4. It just returns an observable. There are other things that matter, including RxJS version and ngrx, I guess. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I've simplified the question slightly in terms of just a console.log and also added my versions.

Comment: Following a break through I have edited my question

Comment: have you tried using `HttpClient` with types definition? something like: `return this.httpClient.delete<SomeTypeFromYourModel>('/api/projects/${id}') ` ?

Comment: Thats my point, this is a simple delete, I don't want to return anything

Comment: in that case you could play with `observe` & `responseType` options passed to `httpClient.delete(url, {responseType: , observe:  })`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems returning a 204 No Content does the trick.

I'm not sure what the logic/reasoning is for 200 not working. Would be good if someone could update.

Code that worked (C#):

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public NoContentResult Delete(int id)
        {
            _projectRepository.Delete(id);

            return new NoContentResult();
        }
```